# Print xml data without outermost root node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is the MXL data -

```
<Root>
<Root1>
  <Child1>
    <GrandChild2 />
    <GrandChild3 />
  </Child1>
  <Child2 />
  <Child3 />
</Root1>
</Root>
```

Below is the desired result -

```
<Root1>
  <Child1>
    <GrandChild2 />
    <GrandChild3 />
  </Child1>
  <Child2 />
  <Child3 />
</Root1>
```

I want to print the same input xml message without the outer most node using xslt.

Thanks in advance for your advice and time!

Comment: So what have you tried? You do not even need XSLT but can select the node(s) with XPath.

Comment: How can I select though XPath?

Comment: I tried using the following link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043764/rename-the-root-node-in-xml-using-xslt

But this is not giving me the result with prefix tag like - "wd:" <wd:Units>3</wd:Units>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```